# Move feature with a mouse without using the Editor widget?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, move

Using ArcGIS Maps SDK for Javascript 4.28, is it possible to Move a feature in a featureLayer, without using the [Editor widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Editor.html)?

The Editor widget has a mode whereby after Selecting a feature, when you mouse-over the feature the cursor changes to a cross-hair and you can drag and drop the feature to a new location. From the debugger Network tab it's apparent that this editing occurs in-memory on the client, and no changes are made until the Update button sends an `updates` request to the layer's `ApplyEdits` endpoint.

[image]

I would like to emulate this behaviour directly in the ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript, without using the Editor widget.

That is, hovering over a feature should show the crosshairs cursor, and dragging the mouse button should move the feature (rather than the default of panning the map).

I can detect when the mouse is over a feature using [hitTest](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#hitTest) on the view, but I can't figure out how to change the drag behaviour to move the feature rather than panning the map.

In addition to the Editor widget there is the [Editor View Model](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Editor-EditorViewModel.html) and [Edits class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Editor-Edits.html), and various [Workflows](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Editor-UpdateWorkflow.html) which look promising - but the documentation for these is minimal.

Is it possible to enter the "Select feature" then "Move feature" modes programatically, without invoking the Editor widget?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to move features with a mouse by hovering over feature and pressing mouse button? If that's correct, please edit your question and state this clearly.

Comment: @TomazicM that's correct - I've included additional information above. Thanks

Comment: It looks like Sketch widget (see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sketch-update-validation/) might be your solution. I tried to make it work on this example https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-editor-configurable/, but didn't succeed, Arcgis is not my area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move features without the Editor widget, using it's underlying "sketch" functionality. The Sketch widget provides a simple UI for creating and updating graphics, but in your case you're probably looking for the SketchViewModel which is the logic behind the Sketch widget UI.

See for example https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sketch-update-validation/